# Drawing an image from svg url in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, sharpvectors

This is the URL with image-https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/acid.svg

What I have tried
Sample 1-
-I am using SharpVectors package

```
public void DrawImage()
{
            Image svgImage = new Image();
            WpfDrawingSettings settings = new WpfDrawingSettings();
            settings.IncludeRuntime = false;
            settings.TextAsGeometry = true;

            FileSvgReader converter = new FileSvgReader(settings);
            DrawingGroup drawing = converter.Read(new Uri("https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/acid.svg"));

            if (drawing != null)
            {
                svgImage.Source = new DrawingImage(drawing);
            }
}
```

sample 1 works perfectly but it's latency is very high, So I wanted to improve the performance.

Sample 2 - I tried using bitmap to improve performance below is code, but the issue is I need to download the image or store in folder and use as path as string which works fine **but my condition is my URLs are coming form JSON file in .SVG format, they are dynamic and I am not using any .XAMl files for UI.**
UI built in code behind programmatically.
Is there any other way I can display SVG image in WPF?

```
public void DrawImage()
{
            Image dynamicImage = new Image();
            dynamicImage.Width = 300;
            dynamicImage.Height = 200;
            stcdock.Children.Add(dynamicImage);

            WpfDrawingSettings settings = new WpfDrawingSettings();
            settings.IncludeRuntime = true;
            settings.TextAsGeometry = false;
            string svgTestFile = @"\Downloads\acid.svg";
            StreamSvgConverter converter = new StreamSvgConverter(settings);

            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            if (converter.Convert(svgTestFile, memStream))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmap.StreamSource = memStream;
                bitmap.EndInit();

                dynamicImage.Source = bitmap;
            }
}
```

Comment: StreamSvgConverter has a Convert method that takes a Stream as first argument, instead of a file path. Download the URL content, copy it into a MemoryStream and use that as input.

Comment: there are many urls , so downloading the content I am not looking for that

Comment: You would download only the one you are going to convert. It's five lines of code, but good luck anyway.

Comment: Actually all urls are required for the UI  that is the issue...

Comment: So you have to download all of them. There is no way around that. If you do it or a library doesn't matter.

Comment: okay.. thank you I will try that way ...

Answer (score -1):

.svg are not nativly supported in wpf.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/svg

This package promisses to add this functionality.

Comment: yes, I know .svg not supported, I tried this package but not getting any success.